# How to use partial correlation on compositional (counts) data? (e.g., as described in Erb et al. 2020)

Tags: count-data, logarithm, partial-correlation, compositional-data

I've read through this paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2590197420300082

Which introduced me to the concept of partial correlation.  I typically use Proportionality when calculating pairwise associations between components in compositions:

- https://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1004075
- https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12064-015-0220-8

I'm trying to translate the implementation of using partial correlation on compositional data but I'm having trouble understanding the preferred implementation.

**Is this paper suggesting the partial correlation is performed on CLR transformed data and using the reference covariate as the geometric mean?**

Here's an excerpt from the paper:

[image]